# Conditional formating on an entire row based on contents in one column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that I want to color the font red in an entire row IF the contents in column N contains the word EMPTY.

For example:

if N2=EMPTY then
Format A2 through AG2
.Font.Color = vbRed

I would like to do this in VBA, thoughts?

Currently I can format the N2 cell but can't figure out how to push this across the entire row.

Comment: You could do this using Conditional Formatting. I'm not completely clear if the value in the N column is exactly "EMPTY" or just includes this text, but either way it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just format columns A:AG of the row that you are processing:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Long
    r = 2
    If Cells(r, "N").Value = "EMPTY" Then
        Rows(r).Range("A1:AG1").Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
End Sub
```

---

And, of course, that could be easily be placed into a loop:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 2 To 100
        If Cells(r, "N").Value = "EMPTY" Then
            Rows(r).Range("A1:AG1").Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Note:  If you wanted to format the entire row, and not just columns A:AG, leave the `.Range("A1:AG1")` part out of the statement, so that it just says:

```
Rows(r).Font.Color = vbRed
```

---

Based on comments that you **don't** want to use VBA, just conditional formatting, apply a conditional format based on a formula of `=$N1="EMPTY"` in cell A1, and copy that to whatever cells you want it to apply to:

[image]

Comment: I have a condition already in play, I tried to add this                            With cond3
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    '.Font.Color = vbRed
    Rows(rg).Font.Color = vbRed
Needless to say it didn't work,

Comment: So you don't want to use VBA?  You want to use conditional formatting instead?  That should be just a case of setting the conditional format if `=$N2="EMPTY"` for all cells that you want to colour on row 2.

Comment: I thought that was VBA, sorry I have only taught myself enough to be dangerous this weekend.

Comment: Okay, I should say. I am in behind the code ALT-F11 writing various code to automatically do this work without user input, if here is a simple way I am all for it.

Comment: @user2429563 I have updated the answer to show the conditional formatting you could use, but if you are writing VBA code to apply conditional formatting (I've never really understood why people do that - if you are running VBA, you may as well apply the formatting directly) then update the question to show what you are doing so that we can help you fix the code.

Comment: Thanks, I add your first comments into my code and it worked perfect. Although I did have to change the range from 100000, anyway of coding this to the bottom of the table. Appreciate it. LOL now on to my next dilemma how I sort my pivot tables with a specific "customer sort" through VBA...if you haven't figure out I am trying to make my life easier by having all this stuff done automatically.

Comment: @YowE3K as an example, AFAIK removing and adding all conditional formatting programmatically is the only way to keep conditional formatting Applies To the same, because cut, copy, and other operations can mess it up

Comment: @Slai I hate conditional formatting because it tends to get "fragmented", especially if you copy/insert a range, so I tend to always just apply formatting via VBA (**without** using conditional formatting).  When I do use conditional formatting on a sheet (which would only be if I have absolutely no need for VBA for any other reason on that sheet), I usually have to be very careful to just copy/paste formulas or copy/paste formatting, rather than a "full" copy/paste.  If Microsoft removed the concept of Conditional Formatting from Excel, I would certainly not mourn its loss.