# conditional formatting a line based on a value

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

On this topic
[Conditional formating on an entire row based on contents in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46269841)

I used method#2 with the loop.  My question is what is the coding I need to add and change to make the cell dark blue, the font white, and bold? (I can live without the bold). Below is my code (text color is red, just to prove to me it worked).  The report is a daily download emailed, and I am currently doing conditional formatting every day and need a faster way.

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    Dim r As Long
    For r = 2 To 100
        If Cells(r, "C").Value = "Night" Then
            Rows(r).Range("b1:p1").Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: In this case, the macro recorder may be helpful. Record applying this formatting manually, and then inspect in the generated code.

Comment: Add a new line below the one you have now in the loop. Type `Rows(r).Range("b1:p1").Font.` and see what possibilities are shown in the popup list. You should be able to figure it out.